# How can I update file in my working directory with a file from different branch?

Tags: mercurial

I am working in branch `Feature` and another developer has finished merging his branch `Feature2` with `Default`. I would like to simply pull one of the files from the now default branch to my branch, before merging my feature (as it is not complete yet).

Comment: Thanks for the formatting changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial works in changesets, not files, so you can't use traditional pull/push to do this.

You can use:

```
hg cat -r Feature2 path/to/thefile > path/to/thefile
```

to get a copy of the modified file.  Or use:

```
hg revert -r Feature2 path/to/thefile
```

which does the same thing.  You could also 'export' and 'import' using -I to include only that  file, but there's no benefit in creating a new single-file changeset.

When later you merge into Default the identical files will merge cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

**graft** (Hg v2.0.2) allows you selectively copy changes from other branches onto the current branch.

```
hg graft [OPTION]... REVISION...

This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes from
other branches without merging branches in the history graph. This is
sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'. By default, graft
will copy user, date, and description from the source changesets.
```